# How are properties of mutable variables shared among multiple variable references?

Tags: java, mutable

I'm not sure if this is just me, or if its something I should have known, but if I do :

```
Object a = 1;
Object b = a;
b = 2;
```

Then a is the same value as b. Is this normal behaviour? Because I wanted to copy the variable, not reference it.

The reason i ask is i have some code like this :

```
center = new Point(0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
returnPoint = center;
...
returnPoint.x = 1.0f;
//For some reason, above modifies center as well as return
```

Comment: Your two examples are not exactly same. Have you tested the first code? I don't think it will change `a` too.

Comment: I have, i've got all these output lines all down the code to check the values in returnPoint, yet it doesnt change (like i want it not to) until i modify center

Comment: Java passes references by value - this is exactly how it it supposed to work.

Comment: Is it? Right, say i want to copy center, not point to the original one, how do i do that?

Comment: You need to actually create a copy at some point.

Comment: @DuskFall I asked you whether you've tested the `Obejct a, b` code. Does it really changes the value of `a`? It can never do that.

Comment: @DuskFall: You've missed Rohit's point - in your first example, if you print `a` it will still print 1, contrary to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
center = new Point(0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
returnPoint = center.clone();
...
returnPoint.x = 1.0f;
```

The clone method will create another instance with the same values.

Comment: Does it work like that with enums too? As in, will i need to clone them too?

Comment: Java enums are not clonable. By design, there should be only 1 instance of each value of your enum on the JVM.

Comment: Oh good, see i'm writing a game engine (Like absolutely everyone does) and i was wondering why the returnPoint was changing each time the entity moved

Comment: check out those books: http://www.amazon.com/Killer-Game-Programming-Andrew-Davison/dp/0596007302/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1394197597&sr=8-1&keywords=java+game+programming and http://www.amazon.com/Developing-Games-Java-David-Brackeen/dp/1592730051/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1394197597&sr=8-2&keywords=java+game+programming

Answer (score 2):

In "returnPoint = center" you don't copy center, you make a reference to it. Thus when you modify returnPoint, you also modify center.

Answer (score 2):

> Then a is the same value as b

No. By doing `b = 2`, you do `b = new Integer(2);`. Therefore `a` and `b` are not the same anymore.

As to your second example this is normal: `returnPoint` is the *same reference* as `center`; if you modify the contents of `returnPoint`, you modify those of `center` since they "refer" to the exact same object. You need to make a copy of `center`.

One solution other than `.clone()` is to make a copy constructor (ie, taking another `Point` as an argument).

Answer (score 2):

Your example

```
Object a = 1;
Object b = a;
b = 2;
```

does not describe the same problem as your other code. The above example will result in `a = new Integer(1)` while `b = new Integer(2)`. Note that integer instances are immutable, something that does not hold for `Point`.

For understanding what went wrong, consider a mutable integer class:

```
class MutableInteger {
  public int value;
}
```

Now let us use this class to recreate the problem in the `Point`-related code for your first example code:

```
MutableInteger mi = new MutableInteger();
mi.value = 1;
Object a = mi;
Object b = a;
mi.value = 2;
```

would result in both `a` and `b` pointing to the same instance of `MutableInteger`. Since you change the latter instance's value, the change of `b` will effect the value referenced by `a`. It will however not change the assignment of `a`!

In order to avoid your problem, you should not share the `Point` instance. Use:

```
returnPoint = new Point(center);
```

in order to create a new point that describes the same coordinates. You can than mutate the copied point without altering the representation of the `center` point.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, if you have two variables of a data type that is not primitive, setting on equal to the other does not give you a clone.  You have to explicitly clone the first variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the value, you'll need to have 3 float variables and store the value inside they. But remember to use "float", not "Float".